# Плывет сайт в mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста почему может плыть сайт на браузере mozilla firefox?
В других браузерах сайт отображается корректно, но в mozilla все наплывает друг на друга
Вот пример mozilla [image: Mozilla]
Вот пример chrome [image: Chrome]
Помогите это исправить, если нужно что-то ещё пишите
Думаю проблемма в этом блоке. Html код, стилей нет

```html
<div class="delimiter">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Реализованные проекты</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content-panel-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="all">
          <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
          <article id="slider">
            <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
            <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
            <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
            <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch4">
            <div id="slides">
              <div id="overflow">
                <div class="image">
                  <article><img src="image/1.png"></article>
                  <article><img src="image/2.png"></article>
                  <article><img src="image/3.png"></article>
                  <article><img src="image/4.png"></article>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="controls">
              <label for="switch1"></label>
              <label for="switch2"></label>
              <label for="switch3"></label>
              <label for="switch4"></label>
            </div>
            <div id="active">
              <label for="switch1"></label>
              <label for="switch2"></label>
              <label for="switch3"></label>
              <label for="switch4"></label>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой ответ. Всё дело в кривой вёрстке. P.S.: Уверен, что с IE дело будет еще хуже, особенно старых версий...  А что нужно, чтобы исправить: Исходники того, что не правильно отображается по Вашему мнению.. .

Comment: Добавил код блока

Comment: Эта страница есть в интернете? Так было бы  проще посмотреть...  Дело скорее больше в CSS.

Comment: class="row"  нужен из CSS